# ubuntu 13.10 64bit No working usb

Tags: usb, keyboard

Well I installed Ubuntu 13.10 fresh install and updated it ..etc

One day I was downloading "Wine" then i left my pc open and slept .

I woke up and of course the Lock Screen was on "The screen where it shows that you must type your password to continue" then i noticed that my keyboard didn't type anything neither my mouse moved " basically mouse + keyboard froze .

I tried unplugging them and re-plugging them but it didn't work .

I restarted the computer "Cold Boot" and then choose Ubuntu again . but after the Boot Selection Screen that let me choose from ubuntu and ubuntu recovery ..etc everything went well but i noticed that my mouse and keyboard stopped working ..etc all USB devices

It's not usb 3.0 it's 2.0 .

Every USB Device that is connected to my pc stop working after booting ubuntu .

I tested the usb deviced it still work on another pc .

and it works before ubuntu start . { It work in GRUB Boot Loader Selection Screen }

I tried to choose ubuntu recovery mode but after booting recovery my keyboard ..etc doesn't work .

So how i can fix this ?

I won't re install ubuntu this is my 3rd re installing it .

Comment: Can you upload try with another keyboard/mouse?

Comment: I tried other keyboard and mice and even some USB devices simply Ubuntu after booting doesn't detect any USB device .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after letting the system upgrade with the Ubuntu upgrade tool last week. Luckily I had an older kernel still in the grub advanced menu, which worked. If you don't have another (older) initramfs/kernel, the only wayout will be to boot an installation medium, chroot the 13.10 and run apt-get upgrade that way.

Problem was a bug. They did not include all included USB drivers for the keyboard in the initramfs (dated 10th October): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1238194

The bug-fix just arrived. I rebooted and it works here now, i.e. upgrading to 13.10 now should pull the fixed package.

Comment: unrelated. the usb fails once ubuntu is fully booted, not before the boot. I have the same problem: install 13.10 on an usb jkey, update it, reboot it, then no keyboard/mice.